# Understanding Concept of Lowerbound and Upperbound in Random Number Generation?

Tags: java, random, lower-bound, upperbound

I'm new at Java and trying to understand the concept of generating a random number within a specific range (of **500000** to **999999**).

I wrote a function:

```
public int generateRandom(){

   Random random = new Random();
   return (int num = random.nextInt(900000) + 500000));

}
```

From what I get is that:

**1.** The `+ 500000` is the lowerbound so that the method will not generate any random number below that value, correct?

**2.** Will the upperbound of `900000` combined with lowerbound of `+ 500000` generate a max value of `1400000`?

Because if `random.nextInt(900000)` returns a `900000` and then theres the `+ 500000` then it will all add up to `1400000` which will make my method not correct if I want to only generate numbers between **500000** to **999999**?

Comment: Correct. You want to return `random.nextInt(upper - lower) + lower`. Or you can use `ThreadLocalRandom.nextInt(origin, bound)`.

Comment: Correct. However, you also should avoid creating a new `Random` on every method invocation. That can impact results because in a loop the seed might not change.